# Word/phrase that describes someone that doesn't do anything without something happening

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes someone that doesn't take action until something adverse happens.

For example, this person sees a leaking pipe, but doesn't get it fixed until it finally burst.

Another example is this person sees structural damage in a building, but didn't get it retrofitted until it came crashing down. They then took action by asking for rescuers to rescue trapped people.

Comment: Can you use 'Johnny come lately' as a delayed starter?

Comment: Something like *penny-wise, pound-foolish* except that it isn't parsimony that leads to the shortsighted (in)action but just laziness/stupidity/unspecified lack of motivation?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a **procrastinator** (or synonyms **postponer**, **cunctator**).
Adjective form is *procrastinatory*.

freedictionary.org:

> **[procrastinator](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=procrastinator)** [Wordnet 3.0]
>
> *NOUN* (1)
>
> **1**. someone who postpones work (especially out of laziness or habitual carelessness);
>   [syn: **postponer**, **cunctator**]
>
> **[Procrastinatory](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=procrastinatory)**
>   *a.*    Of or pertaining to procrastination; dilatory.
>   [1913 Webster]